# Invalidating Microsoft Teams meeting Join URL

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am creating a component that makes use of Microsoft's Graph API to automatically prepare teams meetings, and sends the *Join Meeting URL* to the users that should join the meeting.

It looks like once this link is created it can be used at any time for an indefinite number of times. My issue with this is that I want this URL to be used only once; if the users need to set up another meeting they should go through the system and create another meeting. To enforce this I want to invalidate the meeting URL once the meeting is done, so the user does not have the option of simply reusing the same meeting. I have tried deleting the meeting, however this does not seem to disable the meeting link.

Does anyone have any idea if there is a way to invalidate a teams meeting URL?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your ask or share any repro steps?

Comment: I am following the steps described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings to create the meeting, then share the joinWebUrl returned as part of the response with the users that should attend the meeting; My question is, is there a way to invalidate the joinWebUrl, as once created, that link seems to remain active (I tried moving the meeting date to the past/future as well as deleting the meeting altogether...but no matter what, that link still works).

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any way to invalidate/expire the joinWebUrl.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any way to invalidate/expire the joinWebUrl.